# Web.config redirect from http to https for some sub-site

Tags: asp.net, .net, redirect, web-config

So Ive been googling and browsing similar topics on SO for a while now without finding a solution and figured I might just ask.

I have a master site with several child sites/pages.
In my Web.config file for the master site (affecting all child sites/pages) I have the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

This rule redirect all requests to any page/site under the master site to https:// which have been the intention for some time.

Now however, I have 4 child sites (4 pages under the master site with their own URLs) which I do not want to use https:// for. Lets call them www.apa.com, www.bepa.com, www.cepa.com, www.depa.com. I read some comment on [this similar topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/292374/redirect-users-from-https-to-http-via-iis-and-the-web-config-file) that said it is possible to make exclusions in rules like this, but I did not get it to work.

So I guess I am looking for either a seperate rule or some exclusion to this current rule, that keeps http for my four new child sites and redirects all other sites/pages to https (as it is currently).

**EDIT:**
So I took a different approach. Now I am instead trying to say which sites should redirect to https. The following regex seems to work perfect in a regex tester, but when applied in the web.config file, nothing happens:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(something\.somethingelse\.com\/?)(.*)$
```

If this regex is matched, Id like to redirect all requests to https and if it is not matched it should remain http. In the web.config file this looks like:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https">
      <match url="/^(https?:\/\/)?(something\.somethingelse\.com\/?)(.*)$/"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However this doesnt seem to do anything. Its like it is not possible to match on a full URL or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*SomeWordFromMyUrl*)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```